# Get value in foreach-loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to list all "Usergroups", and if a value exists in the "UsergroupPrices" show it in the textbox. But I'm not sure how to get hold of the value.

```
<% foreach (var item in Model.Usergroups)                                   
   {
    var price = Model.BookingObject.UsergroupPrices.Where(x => x.UsergroupID == item.UsergroupID).Select(x => x.Price);
%>
<tr>
   <td><%= Html.Hidden("UsergroupIDPrice", item.UsergroupID) %><%= item.UsergroupName %>:</td>
   <td><%= Html.TextBox("UsergroupPrice", price) %></td>
</tr>
<% } %>
```

Price is decimal, and may be null if usergroup doesnt have any price.

TIA

/Lasse

Comment: What type of relation is between UserGroups and UsergroupPrice ? describe your entity relation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're just looking for `Single` or possibly `SingleOrDefault`:

```
var price = Model.BookingObject.UsergroupPrices
                               .Where(x => x.UsergroupID == item.UsergroupID)
                               .Select(x => (decimal?) x.Price)
                               .SingleOrDefault();
```

(The cast to `decimal?` is to make `SingleOrDefault` return a null `decimal?` value instead of 0 if there's no match found.)

Note that your current code will be making lots of database queries though, assuming these are actually associated with database contexts. You should probably be doing these queries in the controllers, not the view... Fetch all the data you need in the controller, and put it in the model in the simplest fashion for the view to display.

Answer (score 2):

You need to select a single record:

```
var price = Model
    .BookingObject
    .UsergroupPrices
    .Where(x => x.UsergroupID == item.UsergroupID)
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Price);
```

and then you can test if price is null.

This being said I must say that what you are doing is wrong. It is not the view's responsibility to fetch data. This should be done by the controller. The controller should populate a view model and pass this model to the view. This view model contain all the necessary properties required by the view so that inside the view you only have to show them. **Code like this doesn't belong to a view**.

So I would more than strongly recommend you deporting this logic into the controller as right now you are violating the MVC pattern.